# Adding experimental options to selenium chrome driver

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Does anyone know where i can find a list of experimental options for chromedriver selenium python?

```
opt = Options()
opt.add_experimental_option("mobileEmulation", { "deviceName": "Pixel 2" })
opt.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", "localhost:8989")
opt.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
```